# MobaXterm - reset by peer on SSH server

Tags: ssh, reset, peer

I am using MobaXterm and it does really almost all what I need.

Nevertheless, on some server I was not able to connect to it through SSH.
As it is working with putty, I have from MobaXterm "Read from socket failed : Connection reset by peer".

Is anybody face this behavior ? For information, I have this error only on few of my servers, others are working fine ?

I am using MobaXterm v7.0 home version.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem before, but it has been solved in MobaXterm version 7.1:

- download [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) version 7.1 or later
- go to the global settings window
- navigate to the "SSH" tab
- check the following box: Workaround for "connection reset by peer" issue

Comment: Note: In my case this box was already checked, but not the other one saying "Enable SSH keepalive". That last checkbox solved my issue.